How would I calculate the flux of a given vector field through a surface?
I'm trying to work out a problem where I need to calculate the flux of the vector field $A= \langle xy, yz, zx \rangle$ through the shape pictured below.

So far I've set up the following integral...
$\oint_{S} \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathrm{d} \mathbf{a}$ ; with $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{a}$ being an infintesimally small area.
And I've worked it out to the following result:
$$\begin{align*}
\oint_{S} \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{a} 
&= \int_S \left( xy \, \mathrm{d}y \, \mathrm{d}z + yz \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}z + zx \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y \right) \\
&= \int_0^c \int_0^b xy \, \mathrm{d}y \, \mathrm{d}z + \int_0^c \int_0^a yz \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}z + \int_0^b \int_0^a xy \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y
\end{align*}$$
Is there no way around evaluating these three double integrals, or did I just do the problem wrong?
I know I can get the same answer by evaluating $\int \nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}\, \mathrm{d}\tau$ over the volume of the shape, but I specifically want to know how to setup the problem using the surface integral.

I think it bears noting that your setup leaves out a simplification, and perhaps with that simplification a sort of repetitive structure amongst the three double integrals can be exploited to (for all intents and purposes) reduce the calculation of each to that of just one.
First, though:

What kind of surface is this?
I think this bears extra mention, since it was a mistake I often saw my students perform when teaching multivariable calculus this past spring.
Based on your partial answer, the surface you wish to deal with has three faces. From the front, it looks like this:

But then from the back, it looks like this:

(Play around with it in this Desmos demo if you want.)
The key part: this surface is not closed, and to use the divergence theorem you need a closed surface. There are three surfaces' worth of flux you would be missing if you used the divergence theorem.
Anyhow. Back to business.

Retreading Your Work:
So, let's label the faces:

So
$$
\newcommand{\Int}[1]{\iint\limits_{\text{#1}}}
\newcommand{\A}{\mathbf{\vec{A}}}
\newcommand{\a}{\mathbf{\vec{a}}}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\n}{\mathbf{\hat{n}}}
\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{\hat{x}}}
\newcommand{\y}{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}
\newcommand{\z}{\mathbf{\hat{z}}}
\newcommand{\r}{\mathbf{\vec{r}}}
\Int{surface} \A \cdot \dd \a
= \Int{front}  \A \cdot \dd \a + \Int{right} \A \cdot \dd \a + \Int{top} \A \cdot \dd \a
$$
But now, notice:

The $x$-values on the front face are fixed to $x=a$
The $y$-values on the right face are fixed to $y=b$
The $z$-values on the top face are fixed to $z=c$

Next, recalling that
$$
\iint\limits_S \mathbf{F} \cdot \dd \boldsymbol{\vec{\sigma}}
= \iint\limits_S \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \, \dd \sigma
$$
where $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is the unit outward normal for the surface, we see that

For the front face, $\n$ should be $\x$
For the right face, $\n$ should be $\y$
For the top face, $\n$ should be $\z$

Thus, taking the respective dot products, and fixing values, we get
$$\begin{align*}
\Int{surface} \A \cdot \dd \a
&= \underbrace{\Int{front} xy \, \dd \sigma
+ \Int{right} yz \, \dd \sigma
+ \Int{top} xz \, \dd \sigma}_{\text{taking of the dot products}} \\
&= \underbrace{a \Int{front} y \, \dd \sigma
+ b \Int{right}  z \, \dd \sigma
+ c \Int{top} x  \, \dd \sigma}_{\text{fixing of values}}
\end{align*}
$$
Next, recalling that, if $S$ is parameterized by $\r(u,v)$ for $(u,v) \in R$, then
$$\newcommand{\nc}{\newcommand}
\nc{\norm}[1]{\left\| #1 \right\|}
\nc{\p}{\partial}
\nc{\pdv}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\dd \sigma = \norm{ \pdv \r u \times \pdv \r v }_2 \, \dd u \, \dd v
$$
and that a natural parameterization of a square $[A,B] \times [C,D]$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is
$$
\left\{ \begin{align*}
\r(u,v) &= u \, \x + v \, \y \\
u &\in [A,B] \\
v &\in [C,D]
\end{align*} \right.
$$
(and similar for other orientations) we see that $\r_u,\r_v$ will always be (possibly up to sign) $\x$, $\y$, or $\z$. Naturally, their cross products will thus be a unit vector, so $\dd \sigma$ will be just whichever amongst $\dd x$, $\dd y$, or $\dd z$ are needed.

Slightly Better Setup:
So, this leaves us with
$$
\Int{surface} \A \cdot \dd \a
= a \int_0^c \int_0^b y \, \dd y \, \dd z
+ b \int_0^c \int_0^a  z \, \dd x \, \dd z
+ c\int_0^b \int_0^a  x  \, \dd x \, \dd y
$$

Making This Less Tedious:
So, we have $3$ double integrals, but it's actually not all that bad, because there's a pattern. Noting that the integrating order can be interchanged, we can say each integral is of the type
$$
\int_0^K \int_0^L \xi \, \dd \xi \, \dd \eta
$$
What this is meant to encode is that each double integral integrates just the variable itself for one variable, and the other variable is entirely left alone. This is very easy to evaluate:
$$
\int_0^K \int_0^L \xi \, \dd \xi \, \dd \eta
= \frac{KL^2}{2}
$$
That is,
$$
\Int{face} \A \cdot \dd \a = (\text{outside const.}) \times (\text{const. for ignored var.}) \times \frac 1 2 (\text{const. for integrated var.})^2
$$
(In the $\xi/\eta$ example above, the "ignored variable" is $\eta$, and the integrated variable is $\xi$.)
Apply that to each integral to do them basically in your head:
$$\begin{align*}
a \int_0^c \int_0^b y \, \dd y \, \dd z &= ac \frac{b^2}{2} \\
b \int_0^c \int_0^a  z \, \dd x \, \dd z &= ba \frac{c^2}{2} \\
c\int_0^b \int_0^a  x  \, \dd x \, \dd y &= cb \frac{a^2}{2}
\end{align*}$$
Sum for the final result.

Thank you for your answer! It was very thorough and informative!

I think we can apply divergence theorem here since flux through remaining faces are zero.
